# How to trace a webrequest created in code sent to a local address

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, client-server, fiddler

This issue is occurring in a C#, .NET 4.0 environment. I tried using Fiddler but it doesn't show up. After searching around, the suggested solution was to change the address of the request from localhost to the machine-name.

This worked on my local machine: after changing the call from localhost to my-machine, fiddler picked it up. The real issue is on a client's staging environment with production code. I can not modify the code there to take this change.

Note, as far as I know, on the client site it should be making the request out to the host name and not localhost anyways.

Also, on my local machine I actually hit localhost in my browser, and it seems to pick those up fine. Just not the request built in code. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're saying: "This works fine on the client's PC but not on my dev PC when using Localhost." Is that correct?

In IE9, I [changed WinINET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/02/10/fiddler-is-better-with-internet-explorer-9.aspx) to enable Fiddler to capture loopback traffic from the browser. Sadly, the .NET Framework hasn't yet adopted support for the `<-loopback>` token, which means that traffic sent to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` bypasses the proxy.